# Explain that there is a one to one correspondence between two points in the coordinate plane and one point in the 4 dimensional coordinate space

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

Explain that there is a one to one correspondence between two points $(x_1,x_2),\space(x_3,x_4)$ in the coordinate plane and one point $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ in the 4 dimensional coordinate space.

This seems to be a question that just seems to be correct by intuition. How could I actually explain this? I was a confused when I saw this in my textbook, especially confused on the ways of "explaining" such things.

Comment: the correspondence is given by $((x_1,x_2),(x_3,x_4))\leftarrow\rightarrow(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$